# Unity is deleting references on start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I try to run my game, unity deletes packages imported with nuget. This is done whenever we go to run it. The packages is specifically TestSharp.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not enough information to help... like, at all. Also i'm not sure it's worthy of a `c#` tag. If you're after help you'll need to be more specific and probably post the question on the unity forums instead of SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use nuget packages with Unity like a regular Visual Studio project. You'll need to add the dll as a plugin. See this question on the Unity forum:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/631546/using-a-nuget-package-jsonnet.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the dll provided by that package, to the plugins folder of the unity project. 
Personally i create a custom c# proyect, import the nugget package there. Then in the postbuild event, i copy the generated dll in the plugins folder of the unity project. Unity should import these dll.